# Android app: Initiate a skype call and close skype when call is finished

Tags: android, kotlin, skype

I have an Android application which initiates a skype call via standard intent. Like this one:

```
val sky = Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW")
sky.data = Uri.parse("skype:<skype_id>")
sky.component = ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider")
startActivity(sky)
```

But after the call is finished user still has to exit skype and go back to my app manually. 
I wonder if it is possible to bring user back to my app right after the call is finished?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
Skype gives notification when call is picked and removes the notification when call is ended.
You could use NotificationManager Class to detect skype notification as soon you get NotificationRemoved Event of package name "com.skype.raider" you could use intent to redirect user to your app.